# Document is undefined when using apollo query with next.js getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo

I am trying to use `getServerSideProps` to fetch a query every time this component is rendered using `apollo` and `next.js`

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: GET_AUTHED_USER
  })
  return {
    props: { user: data.getAuthedUser },
  }

}


const Profile = ({ user }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  // const [state, setState] = useState(JSON.parse(router.query.currentUser));
  const [state, setState] = useState(user);
  console.log(state)
...
```

**APOLLO CONFIG**

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloLink } from '@apollo/client';
import { getCookie } from './utils/functions';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client';

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from storage if it exists
  const token = getCookie('JWT');
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? token : '',
    }
  }
});

const httpLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql',
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: ApolloLink.from([authLink, httpLink])
});

export default client;
```

currently, when visiting the `/profile` page I receive the error:

```
Server Error
Error: document is not defined
```

Does anyone have any insight on how to resolve this or suggest a valid work around?

Answer (score 0):

appolo/client is a client side library. getServersideProps execute in server side. document doesn't exist in server side. It will only work within client side.

**Workaround 1:**

You can use [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/). swr is for client side data fetch. so you don't need getServerSideProps.

**Workaround 2:**

You can use [apollo-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server). Then you can call apollo-server function in getServerSideProps as apollo-server is for server side calling.